# Mobile menu not showing correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a "mobile navigation menu".

I'm following this [CSS Dropdown Menu](http://www.queness.com/post/13093/responsive-mobile-navigation-menumethods-and-solutions) (look at CSS Drop Down menu paragraph and its resources).

When i click to "Menu" button to open my menu, submenu voices override "Menu" button, so i cannot close menu when it's opened.

Here's my CSS code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    #access .nav-toggle{
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width:50%;
    }

    #menu-navigazione {
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 10000000;
       display: block;
       width:40% !important;
    }

    #menu-navigazione li {
       display: block;
    }

    #menu-navigazione li a {
       display: block;
    }
```

And this is my HTML structure

```
<a class="nav-toggle" href="#">Menu</a>
<div class="menu-navigazione-container">
 <ul id="menu-navigazione" class="menu" style="display: block;">
  <li><a href="#">Some content HERE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some other content HERE</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Where am i doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share the fiddle with your code

Comment: Sure, sorry but i was able to post only one link :) http://jsfiddle.net/UQj9m/ (this is not the whole code of the page, because it's only a little part of a wordpress page). Here my test: http://93.57.93.221:81/fenicepool_documentazione/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this css

```
.menu-navigazione-container {
   position: relative;
}
#menu-navigazione {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 10000000;
   display: block;
   width:40% !important;
   top:42px;
   left:0px;
}
```